# cannot connect to github, not able to clone or push repo

Tags: github, firewall, antivirus

It was working fine until tomorrow.
But today I am not able to push changes to the repo.
I tried to clone my repo, it also shows the same error.

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/nkp1111/python-projects.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443 after 21101 ms: Timed out
```

The same error is showing up. I haven't changed any setting to my knowledge.
It started to clone and stop after one time.

I suspect it is because of antivirus.

What can i do to make it work again?

Comment: looks like repo server is down for some reason, or maybe firewall config changed? Reasons may be various.

Comment: This question is not within the context of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many causes for the problem, and we will not be able to solve your problem other than suggesting what to do.

have you set any security with temporary credentials? otherwise, it is most possibly also temporary.

try to clone some other repositories, any repository, to test the connection. if you fail to do that, then rest assured it is a temporary GitHub issue.

then try to clone your repo again. if you can clone but can't push back, then you will need to dig into security settings, first on GitHub, then on your computer.

PS: I can clone your repo right now, so I can say GitHub is working toward my country right now.

Comment: It started working with the terminal command after I config with my username and email again. But it always asks for token or browser for the commit to follow.

Comment: @nkp1111, I think you have changed some settings relating to security, but I am failing to see/remember what it can be. try to save/push your work, remove it from your pc, and then clone it again and see if it is still the same.

Comment: I have create a new access token and use it for verification. Now I can push changes to the repo with terminal but when I try to push via Pycharm shortcut it still asks for token.

Comment: @nkp1111, if it works that way, keep it like that. just do not let your token slip outside ;) I suggest you set a timeout to your token, weekly maybe!?.

Comment: @nkp1111, I missed the pycharm part, I guess it has a setting to use token. look for it and set it.

Comment: I tried with Vscode its working fine its just Pycharm that asks for token. I think I might have to take a look at settings of pycharm. but it seems everything working fine. Thank you for your time for everything.